# How to get Primefaces Marker Data via jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, web, primefaces, google-maps-markers

I'm using Primefaces (5.1) Marker to add markers on my map.
It works fine but with all other informations like lat and lng I want to pass some Object Data and to do that i'm using the setData(Object data) method.
My problem is that I don't know how to retrieve this information via jQuery.

Am I doing it right? If this is the right way how can i retrieve this information?

```java
Marker marker = new Marker(myLatLng, myTitle, myObjectData, myIcon, myShadow);
```

```js
var map = PF('map').getMap();

//here is my problem
map.markers[0].???? = myData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getPlace()` method, which returns a Place object, from the Place object, you can get the lat and long of a marker location. Or you can call `getPosition()` to return lat or long of the marker.

[**information**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker)

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for answer me!

Actually my problem isn't to get the lat and lng but to
obtain the "extra data" that I want to put on the markers.

In my example I show it as "myObjectData" in the Marker construtor... That information I need to retrieve via jQuery.
Do you have any idea of how can I do that?